# React Native Initial project typescript error

Tags: typescript, react-native

I initially created my project using `react-native init` but checking on App.tsx there has several error

[image]

can you guys tell me why i am having this issue?

the `tsconfig.json` only use this

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json"
}
```

do i forget something to setup?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the project with:
`npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject`

Look:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

From version 0.71 the typescript is already coming by default:
https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/01/12/version-071

Comment: yup that is what i did but initially i got typescript errors.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding item into file: Association on vscode settings

[image]